# Is it possible to launch Firefox with a specific about:config setting from the terminal?

Tags: firefox, terminal, configuration, config, user-agent

I'm dealing with a site which does not play well with my operating system unless I override my user agent string. (Then it performs perfectly, so I'm chalking this up to an inexperienced person being given objectively the wrong job...)

However, I do not want to leave that user agent string consistently changed. Unfortunately, Firefox does not allow for simply disabling a setting, and this is a fairly long string to remember. I'm wondering, because of that, if it is possible for me to simply launch it from terminal with a parameter that adds this specific about:config setting?

If not, is there a proxy that might allow me to mask it? I'm just looking for a quick and effective solution here, which requires less work than re-entering a lengthy about:config string and potentially restarting my browser.

Thanks to anyone who thinks they may have a solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create second Firefox profile, change this setting in this second profile and run firefox:

```
firefox -p name_of_profile
```

The good point is both profiles will be independent and you can run two instances of Firefox simultaneously with different profile.